# Initialize a hash with all 0 values based on two arrays

Tags: ruby, hash-map

Given two arrays (for instance a list of people and a list of subjects), I need to initialise a `Hash` with all zeros for all possible combinations of these two arrays. I can manage to do that with the code on the bottom, but it seems like there should be a less convoluted, more elegant way to do this.

```
people = %w(tom mary rob)
subjects = %w(math english)

Hash[people.map { |person| [person, Hash[subjects.map { |subject| [subject, 0] }]]}]

# output: => {"tom"=>{"math"=>0, "english"=>0},
# "mary"=>{"math"=>0, "english"=>0},
# "rob"=>{"math"=>0, "english"=>0}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually, that's the way to go. I'd just propose some small changes:

- Use [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) instead of [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)
- This line is too long, split it in multiple lines.

So I'd write:

```
scores = people.map do |person|
  person_scores = subjects.map { |subject| [subject, 0] }.to_h 
  [person, person_scores]
end.to_h
```

Answer (score 4):

While you can do this in one line, there's really no need. At least you can break the line into `do..end` blocks to keep things more readable.

But moreso, I'd consider `dup`ing the zeros hash (presumably grades for the subjects so I'll call it that) once you've built it, rather than build and re-build it for each person.

Also, you can use `each_with_object` (a sort of `reduce`) instead of wrapping a mapped array in `Hash[..]`.

For instance,

```
grades = subjects.each_with_object({}) { |subject, hash| hash[subject] = 0 }
people.each_with_object({}) { |name, hash| hash[name] = grades.dup }
```

But there are many ways to go about this. While it's a little outside the task, you could simply initialize a Hash with default value of zero for unknown keys:

```
grades = Hash.new(0)
grades["math"] #=> 0
grades["no a real subject"] #=> 0
```

Of course, as the last line shows, you'll get zero for any key, even if it doesn't really make sense. Usually you'd of course just get a `nil`. You'll also want to be careful with this approach in general, if the default value is an object, since it won't automatically `dup` itself; it'll be the same object (same object reference) for every key. It's not a problem with numbers though.

Still, it'd condense things to one line again:

```
people.each_with_object({}) { |name, hash| hash[name] = Hash.new(0) }
```

A more precise alternative, that only creates the required keys, could be:

```
grades = Hash[ subjects.zip(Array.new(subjects.size, 0)) ]
```

And of course, recent versions of Ruby have a `to_h` method that lets you chain the call, rather than wrap an array in it:

```
grades = subjects.map { |subject| [subject, 0] }.to_h
people.map { |name| [name, grades.dup] }.to_h
```

Which is close to what you started with, just using `dup`.

There are even more ways to do things - this is just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

I did start with this:

```
~/ (main) > notes = Array.new(subjects.size,0)
=> [0,0]

~/ (main) > Hash[[people, Array.new(people.size, Hash[[subjects, notes].transpose])].transpose]
=> {
     "tom" => {
           "math" => 0,
        "english" => 0
    },
    "mary" => {
           "math" => 0,
        "english" => 0
    },
     "rob" => {
           "math" => 0,
        "english" => 0
    }
}
```

But there is a pattern: make a hash with keys from a supplied array and all with the same value. Then a lambda could help:

```
~/ (main) > head_val_to_h = ->(head, val) { Hash[[head, Array.new(head.size, val)].transpose]}
=> #<Proc:0x00000008bce460@(pry):55 (lambda)>

~/ (main) > head_val_to_h[people, head_val_to_h[subjects, 0]]
=> {
     "tom" => {
           "math" => 0,
        "english" => 0
    },
    "mary" => {
           "math" => 0,
        "english" => 0
    },
     "rob" => {
           "math" => 0,
        "english" => 0
    }
}
```